# To Terraform and CDK experts: How to manage this in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, aws-cdk

Best practice to manage multiple stacks with Terraform in replacement of CDK

Hi all. In my previous company, we manage the AWS Resources with CDK CloudFormation. Basically, there are three AWS accounts for one project:

- Dev account: For development and verification purpose. Any CDK and application code changes like AWS Lambda can be deployed from developer's local machine directly. The developer can check if the AWS Resources are created with his/her changes after that deployment from AWS console.
- QA account: A test account before deployed to prod environment.
- Prod account: A production environment account.

So the development workflow is (see screenshot):

1. A developer (say dev1) git pulls the code repo.
2. Add new AWS resources, e.g. AWS Lambda with CDK, where the name of Lambda is defined as "{env/user}-any-Lambda", and application code for it in his/her local machine.
3. Build the code and run cdk deploy to deploy to Dev account. The developer dev1 has his/her own CloudFormation stack, which contains a set of AWS resources, including new "dev1-any-Lambda". So it wouldn't interfere with other developers' stacks.
4. Once Dev1 confirms the AWS Lambda was created in AWS account and verify that functionality, he/she would create a merge request, code review, get approved and git push to repo.
5. CI/CD pipeline would deploy that code to QA account.
6. If QA account's resources look good to CI/CD pipeline (e.g. with integration test), it would deploy to prod.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyKUc.png)

My current company uses Terraform. I learnt that Terraform has nothing to do with CloudFormation, and it manages AWS resources in an AWS account with terraform workspace (correct me if I'm wrong). If seems that it's not straightforward to do the similar thing as my previous company does.

To terraform experts: Is it possible to similar thing in Terraform, so that if there are multiple developers in a team, they wouldn't interfere each other and can verify their code changes with their own stack in Dev account? I know you can somehow verify if your terraform code is correct with "terraform plan", but that doesn't create a developer-owned-stack in AWS. Or any best practice of using terraform when there are multiple developers in a team?

Thanks!

Comment: Or simply speaking, how to you usually test your terraform code change locally, so that you are sure your terraform code + application code works as expected after pushed to QA and PROD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To terraform experts: Is it possible to similar thing in Terraform, so that if there are multiple developers in a team, they wouldn't interfere each other and can verify their code changes with their own stack in Dev account?

Absolutely!  What you've described is a great use case for [Terraform Cloud](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cloud-docs).  You'll be able to build out a module that deploys your whole stack.  You have the ability to variablize (and put conditions) on anything you want.  For instance, it sounds like every member of your team wants their own infrastructure in your dev AWS environment.  Take the documentation example for a [Lambda function](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_function):

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "assume_role" {
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["lambda.amazonaws.com"]
    }

    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "iam_for_lambda" {
  name               = "iam_for_lambda"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.assume_role.json
}

data "archive_file" "lambda" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_file = "lambda.js"
  output_path = "lambda_function_payload.zip"
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "test_lambda" {
  # If the file is not in the current working directory you will need to include a
  # path.module in the filename.
  filename      = "lambda_function_payload.zip"
  function_name = "lambda_function_name"
  role          = aws_iam_role.iam_for_lambda.arn
  handler       = "index.test"

  source_code_hash = data.archive_file.lambda.output_base64sha256

  runtime = "nodejs16.x"

  environment {
    variables = {
      foo = "bar"
    }
  }
}
```

We can re-write the function_name argument value as `${var.user}_lambda_function_name` and build out a workspace in Terraform Cloud where the workspace contains the variable values (in this case, their name) for that specific developer.  Terraform Cloud will also handle your [CI/CD configurations](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cloud-docs/vcs).  You'll be able to point Terraform Cloud VCS-integrated workspaces towards specific branches so you can control your deployment strategy.  Every time a developer pushes changes on the targeted branch, Terraform Cloud will kick off a plan and allow you to see the changes that would be made should you apply the plan.  Every change to the lambda.js can get automatically pushed up to AWS in that way.

Anyway this is just a primer - as someone who came from the CloudFormation world as well and hasn't looked back, I can wholeheartedly suggest a migration to Terraform to make your team more productive.  There is a free version of Terraform Cloud if you'd like to kick the tires on it and deploy your first resource into AWS.  I'm happy to answer any other questions you have!

Comment: Hi mleon, thanks for your answer! Is it true that one terraform cloud workspace can only maps to one stack? Let’s say I’m Jason, and the other developer is James. So I need to create “dev-jason” Cloud workspace, and James needs to create “dev-james” cloud workspace? Or maybe in this case, I should create local terraform workspace instead of Cloud workspace for dev account? I would appreciate it you have some real example of code in GitHub repo. Thanks!

Comment: One workspace = one environment. You can create a single GitHub repo with Terraform code and deploy it for 100 different environments or developers. Just make sure you have variables for the differences from environment to environment or developers to developer.

I don't have a fleshed out example, but in my answer I included a code snippet of what this might look like.  You would get a lambda function called "james_lambda_function_name" and "jason_lambda_function_name" by setting the `user` variable.  You could add in something like `${var.environment}` and customize it even more.